# Tornado PUT Request Missing Body

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to make a put request using a tornado ASyncHTTPClient like so:

```
  data = { 'text': 'important text',
           'timestamp': 'an iso timestamp' }

  request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(URL, method = 'PUT', body = urllib.urlencode(data))

  response = yield Task(tornado.httpclient.ASyncHTTPClient().fetch, request)
```

However, when the request hits its desired endpoint, it appears not to have a body, despite said body being properly encoded and defined above. Is there something that I'm overlooking here?

---

Comment: Where are you importing `HTTPRequest` from? And also how are you instantiating the `client`

Comment: HTTPRequest is coming from tornado.httpclient, and client is an alias for tornado.httpclient.ASyncHTTPClient. I'll update the question to make that clear!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you have here. Might be a subtle bug in the handler code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the other end is expecting JSON, you probably need to set a "Content-Type" header. Try this:

```
data = { 'text': 'important text',
       'timestamp': 'an iso timestamp' }

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(URL, method = 'PUT', headers = headers, body = simplejson.dumps(data))

response = yield Task(tornado.httpclient.ASyncHTTPClient().fetch, request)
```

This way, the header tells the server you're sending JSON, and the body is a string that can be parsed as JSON.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is probably on the other end.
The following test using Tornado 2.4.1 yields the expected output.

```
import logging
import urllib

from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler, asynchronous
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPRequest, AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado import gen, options

log = logging.getLogger()
options.parse_command_line()

class PutBodyTest(RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def get(self):
        data = {
            'text': 'important text',
            'timestamp': 'a timestamp'
        }
        req = HTTPRequest(
            'http://localhost:8888/put_body_test',
            method='PUT',
            body=urllib.urlencode(data)
        )
        res = yield gen.Task(AsyncHTTPClient().fetch, req)
        self.finish()

    def put(self):
        log.debug(self.request.body)

application = Application([
    (r"/put_body_test", PutBodyTest),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Log output:

```
$ python put_test.py --logging=debug
[D 130322 11:45:24 put_test:30] text=important+text&timestamp=a+timestamp
[I 130322 11:45:24 web:1462] 200 PUT /put_body_test (127.0.0.1) 0.37ms
[I 130322 11:45:24 web:1462] 200 GET /put_body_test (::1) 9.76ms
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been starting to suspect similar, and running this test case helped confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

**this is post request with expecting JSON! Try this:**

```
    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()

        URL = "http://localhost:1338/api/getPositionScanByDateRange"
        data = {"startDate":"2017-10-31 18:30:00","endDate":"2018-02-08 12:09:14","groupId":3} #A dictionary of your post data
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

        record = yield http_client.fetch(URL, method = 'POST', headers = headers, body = json.dumps(data))

        if record.error:
            response = record.error
        else:
            response = record.body
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        self.finish(response)
```